# PopulateViewHolder runs once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Hi I'm trying to use the FireBaseRecyclerAdapter but only runs populateViewHolder me 1 time, and the database FireBase have more than one element. I have added to FireBaseRecyclerAdapter one AdapterDataObserver and the onItemRangeChanged method if running as many times as items I have in the database but in the populateView still running at once.

I put my code:

FireBase data base:

Code FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:

```
public class MyFireBaseAdapterRecycleView extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModeloDatos,MyFireBaseAdapterRecycleView.MyFireViewHolder> {

public MyFireBaseAdapterRecycleView(Class<ModeloDatos> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<MyFireViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(MyFireViewHolder viewHolder, ModeloDatos modelo, int position) {
    viewHolder.bindDatos(modelo);
}

/** Clase ViewHolder interna */
public static class MyFireViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView uidUsuario;
    private TextView uidImagen;
    public MyFireViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        uidUsuario = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIdUsuario);
        uidImagen = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIdImagen);
    }

    public void bindDatos(ModeloDatos datos){
        uidUsuario.setText(datos.getUidUser());
        uidImagen.setText(datos.getUidImagen());
    }
}
```

Code AdapterDataObserver:

```
public class AdapterFireDataObserver extends RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver {
  @Override
  public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
      super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
  }
}
```

Code Data Model:

```
public class ModeloDatos {
  private String uidUser;
  private String uidImagen;

  public ModeloDatos() {
  }

  public String getUidUser() {
    return uidUser;
  }

  public void setUidUser(String uidUser) {
    this.uidUser = uidUser;
  }

  public String getUidImagen() {
    return uidImagen;
  }

  public void setUidImagen(String uidImagen) {
    this.uidImagen= uidImagen;
  }
}
```

and code from Activty

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_recycle);
adaptador = new MyFireBaseAdapterRecycleView(ModeloDatos.class, R.layout.fila_fire_recycle,
        MyFireBaseAdapterRecycleView.MyFireViewHolder.class, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Imagenes"));
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvSGOliver);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
observer = new AdapterFireDataObserver();
adaptador.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
```